# BigQuery unexpected error

Tags: google-bigquery

Running very simple queries against my table and getting unexpected errors. Anybody from the BQ engineering team able to look at my Job IDs and figure out what's happening here?

```
SELECT field from mydataset.mytable
limit 100

Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: natural-terra-531:job_OhD8zgm8btXQPNuwGSdIMoDX_f4
```

Another one with aggregation:

```
SELECT city, max(timestamp) from mydataset.mytable
GROUP BY city limit 100

Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: natural-terra-531:job_9DjzAgn05yKZSYKCANHNbckE4f8
```

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery service had a temporary glitch last night that caused a high rate of failure for some queries between 10 and 10:30 PM due to a misconfiguration. We're conducting a postmortem to make sure we can prevent it in the future. If you retry the queries, they should work. If they do not, please let us know.

Comment: is there a status page to verify?

Comment: Alas, there is no status page currently.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, My "simple" queries are running again but now i'm trying to use the LAG() function and getting the same error. Job ID: natural-terra-531:job_3GV-VKEQ_21xNKHCKr5EHFDclJA

Comment: My query: SELECT LAG(a,1) OVER (PARTITION BY b ORDER BY c), a
FROM dataset.table
LIMIT 1000;

Comment: You're hitting a known bug relating to timestamps. If you use TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(timestamp) (you may need a subquery because you can't order by a computed field.)

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I'll give that a try. Any ETA on a fix for this?